# python setup.py egg_info failed when installing python-bioformats

Tags: java, python

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04, and I have installed virtualenvs. I am in one env and trying to install python-bioformats
The installation instruction form the official [website](http://pythonhosted.org/python-bioformats/) just indicate to install as:

```
pip install python-bioformats
```

I did but I got the following error message:

```
(env2) daniel@Caenor:~/Envs$ pip install python-bioformats
Collecting python-bioformats
  Using cached python-bioformats-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting javabridge>=1.0 (from python-bioformats)
  Using cached javabridge-1.0.14.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-SUD0_e/javabridge/setup.py", line 375, in <module>
        ext_modules=ext_modules(),
      File "/tmp/pip-build-SUD0_e/javabridge/setup.py", line 93, in ext_modules
        java_home = find_javahome()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-SUD0_e/javabridge/javabridge/locate.py", line 73, in find_javahome
        java_bin = get_out(["bash", "-c", "type -p java"])
      File "/tmp/pip-build-SUD0_e/javabridge/javabridge/locate.py", line 70, in get_out
        raise Exception("Error finding javahome on linux: %s" % cmd)
    Exception: Error finding javahome on linux: ['bash', '-c', 'type -p java']

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SUD0_e/javabridge/
```

I think this means I need the javabridge. I tried to install but I also get an error:

```
(env2) daniel@Caenor:~$ pip install javabridge
Collecting javabridge
  Using cached javabridge-1.0.14.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-KrBfqr/javabridge/setup.py", line 375, in <module>
        ext_modules=ext_modules(),
      File "/tmp/pip-build-KrBfqr/javabridge/setup.py", line 93, in ext_modules
        java_home = find_javahome()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-KrBfqr/javabridge/javabridge/locate.py", line 73, in find_javahome
        java_bin = get_out(["bash", "-c", "type -p java"])
      File "/tmp/pip-build-KrBfqr/javabridge/javabridge/locate.py", line 70, in get_out
        raise Exception("Error finding javahome on linux: %s" % cmd)
    Exception: Error finding javahome on linux: ['bash', '-c', 'type -p java']

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-KrBfqr/javabridge/
```

From the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/javabridge/installation.html#linux) to install the javabridge I need numpy (I already have), the Java Development Kit (JDK) and a C compiler.

I have installed JPype1 (I think this is the JDK)
I tried to install the Javabridge but I got the error again.

What is missing to get the Javabridge and python-bioformats to be installed?

Comment: Do you have `JAVA_HOME` set?

Comment: Ok, I followed this instrucitons to set the JAVA_HOME: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get#setting-the-java_home-environment-variable

Comment: is your issue resolved now? if, not, are you getting the same error?

Comment: Yes, after setting the JAVA_HOME I could pip install python-bioformats without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have note installed Java. You need to install Java on you system. If you think it is installed, then sure it is not on the Linux's paths to search for executables and you need to add the path to Java to environment variable `PATH`. Whenever you have Java installed/add to Linux's `PATH` then execute `type -p java` on command line and it should return the path to the `java` executable.